# how to get exact key's value in array using PHP?

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$response = json_decode($result);
print_r($response);
```

and I got the result

```
  stdClass Object ( [type] => http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/ [title] => Resource Not Found 
[status] => 404 
[detail] => The requested resource could not be found. 
[instance] => )
```

and I added

```
foreach($response as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key.'='.$val.'<br>';
}
```

But I want how to get exact key and value for `detail`. How to get it? 
Thanks

Comment: `->` because you're accessing an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($response as $key => $val){
  echo "Key: " . $key . "Value: " . $val->detail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in json_decode(), you have to pass 2 parameter "true", like this..

```
$response = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($response);
```